# restart a thread after exception is caught

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading a UDP feed and I want the thread to attempt to restart if their is a failure. I think I have written my class correctly but would like someone to look over and see if there is something missing or I have written something that won't get the job done. In my catch clause I attempt to restart the thread every 6 seconds for 10 attempts. Is this a good solution, will it work?

```
class UDPReader extends Thread
{
    private Thread t;
    private final String ip, socket, queue, threadName;
    private String ErrorMessage;
    private final JTextArea screen;

    UDPReader(String ip, String socket, String queue, String threadName, JTextArea screen) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.socket = socket;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.threadName = threadName;
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try {
            byte[] i = null;
            ipaddrConnection ipaddr = new ipaddrConnection(ip, socket);
            parseUDP p = new parseUDP();

            screen.append("Thread " + threadName + " running\n");
            while(true)
            {
                i = ipaddr.getPacket();
                p.parseUDP(i); 
                //Thread.sleep(0);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MarketDataReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ErrorMessage = "Thread " + threadName + " has failed, Attempting to Restart";
            screen.append("Thread " + threadName + " has failed, Attempting to Restart\n");
            Email email = new Email(ErrorMessage,"WARNING Market Data Reader Failure");

            for(int i = 0; i < 10 && t.isAlive() == false; i++)
            {
                try {
                    start();
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex1) {
                    Logger.getLogger(UDPReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                    ErrorMessage = "Thread " + threadName + " has failed, Contact System Administraitor";
                    screen.append("Thread " + threadName + " has failed, Contact System Administraitor\n");
                    email = new Email(ErrorMessage,"WARNING Market Data Reader Failure");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() 
    {
        if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not put the try catch inside the while loop? Also `while(true)` is not a good idea.

Comment: You have over-ridden `Thread.start` to actually start another thread.  Now when I see `start()` called, it is not obvious what happens.  It's not that hard to figure out, but it makes this prone to mistakes.  I would suggest never over-riding `Thread.start`.  That is what `Thread.run` is for.

Comment: What is this `email object` that you never send?

Comment: You are only catching `IOException`.  That may be good, if you are trying to catch a specific exception.  But from the way you worded your question, I think you want to catch any error.  You should maybe catch `Throwable`.

Comment: The more I look at the over-riding of `Thread.start`, the more it bothers me.  It violates the Principle of Least Astonishment.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @Brandon It is also unsafe because the Thread can be erroneously started more than once if `start` is called from multiple threads without synchronization (`t` is not volatile). But it is from [a wrong tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm), the OP did not come up with it.

Comment: Not to mention, for example, calling `join` on an instance of UDPReader will cause the calling thread to halt forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the logic behind your thread in detail but I would make some suggestions on the design of your code.

1. It is not clear why inside a class derived from thread you have another thread t.
2. There is no need to derive from Thread (and I believe it is generally a bad practice). It is common to rather implement `Runnable` interface  and then construct a new thread using it.

.

```
class UDPReader implements Runnable {
...
}
```

and then instantiate a thread like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new UDPReader());
```

3. As a rule, if a thread fails, it terminates... It does not look good that a failed thread "recreates" itself. The better solution would be to provide a `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` and in the code that creates your thread analyze failing conditions and restart you thread if needed.

In general, not to mess up, in concurrent programming you have to clearly distinguish the logic of a thread and external logic that manages this thread (its start/interruption/termination). I think, this is what you did not do in your code.

Comment: For your first question I followed example 1 from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: By calling start inside the catch I thought that I was essentially starting a new thread. The start method creates a new instance of thread, correct?

Comment: @MadMardigans The example in that tutorial is very wrong.

Comment: @Radiodef could you point me to a better example, that would be helpful in learning the correct way to accomplish my goal

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it is a very bad design to restart a thread from inside of the same thread.

If you need a 'supervisor' thread then you should most likely create another 'supervisor' thread that would create and start the 'worker' thread whenever it finds out that 'worker' thread is down.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should be aware of is that when you catch an exception in Java, the program (or thread) does not terminate unless you tell it too.

Therefore, if you caught your exception exactly at the command that caused it to happen - inside the loop - you would not need to run another thread. Your thread is alive and will continue to loop. All you need to do - inside the `catch` block - is fix things up so that the next loop can continue as usual - close and reopen streams, clear partially filled data structures, stuff like that.

Of course, if further, unrecoverable exceptions happen, you should indeed stop your thread.